# Querying for the distinct count used to create a grouped, aggregated, and filtered row set

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have a table that looks like this:

```
control=# select * from animals;
 age_range | weight | species
-----------+--------+---------
 0-9       |      1 | lion
 0-9       |      2 | lion
 10-19     |      2 | tiger
 10-19     |      3 | horse
 20-29     |      2 | tiger
 20-29     |      2 | zebra
```

I perform a query that summarizes weights of animals within age range groups, and I only want to return rows that have aggregated weights above 
a certain number.

Summary Query:

```
SELECT
 age_range,
 SUM(animals.weight) AS weight,
 COUNT(DISTINCT animals.species) AS distinct_species
FROM animals
GROUP BY age_range
HAVING SUM(animals.weight) > 3;
```

Summary Results:

```
 age_range | weight | distinct_species
-----------+--------+------------------
 10-19     |      5 |                2
 20-29     |      4 |                2
```

Now here's the rub. Along with this summary, I want to report the distinct number of species used to create the above summary row set as a whole. For simplicity, let's refer to this number as the 'Distinct Species Total'. In this simple example, since only 3 species (tiger, zebra, horse) were used in yielding the 2 rows of this summary, and not 'lion', the 'Distinct Species Total' should be 3. But I can't figure out how to successfully query for that number. Since the summary query must use a having clause in order to apply a filter to an already grouped and aggregated row set, this presents problems in trying to query for the 'Distinct Species Total'.

This returns the wrong number, 2, because it is incorrectly a distinct count of a distinct count:

```
SELECT
 COUNT(DISTINCT distinct_species) AS distinct_species_total
FROM (
 SELECT
  age_range,
  SUM(animals.weight) AS weight,
  COUNT(DISTINCT animals.species) AS distinct_species
 FROM animals
 GROUP BY age_range
 HAVING SUM(animals.weight) > 3
) x;
```

And of course this returns the wrong number, 4, because it does not consider filtering the grouped and aggregated summary result using a having clause:

```
SELECT
 COUNT(DISTINCT species) AS distinct_species_total
FROM animals;
```

Any help at all in getting leading me on the right path here is appreciated, and will hopefully help others with a similar problem, but in the end I do need a solution that will work with Amazon Redshift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the result set with the original animals table and count the distinct species.

```
select distinct x.age_range,x.weight,count(distinct y.species) as distinct_species_total
from 
(
     select age_range,sum(animals.weight) as weight
     from animals
     group by age_range
     having sum(animals.weight) > 3
) x
join animals y on x.age_range=y.age_range
```

Comment: Nice, clean solution. In reality, my 'animals' table is a derived table that results from several table joins, but your solution applies there as well.